# If baryogenisis had not occurred how would the universe progress and how would it differ from CCC's final stage

Tags: cosmology

If baryogenisis was an error and there were no quarks and leptons remaining, can we assume that inflation would have still occurred and continued without matter. Would other particles have survived in the soup at this stage. Probably neutrinos but what of gluons? Would the annihilations have resulted in a photon universe similar to that of Roger Penrose's Conformal Cyclic Cosmology and if so why would not the cycle be much faster without the black hole scenario.